# Count existence of a record in a table and then update the same table

Tags: mysql, select

I have this table "user" that have the following tables.

```
username refered refcount
 admin              3         //admin refered 3 users.(user1,user3,user6) 
 user1    admin     1
 user3    admin     0
 user4    user3     0
 user5    user1     0
 user6    admin     0
```

What I want to do is count each people that a user referred and save that count to the refcount of each record. But how can I do that?

I tried this but getting an error

```
UPDATE user
SET referrals=(SELECT COUNT(userid) AS refs FROM user WHERE refered=username   )
```

This is the error I get

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0):

There are several examples in stackoverflow. Basically you need to join with itself the `user` table. Also I think your count method was not valid (I didn't test but this should be pretty close):

```
UPDATE user u1
JOIN (
     SELECT u2.userid, COUNT(u2.userid) AS refs
     FROM user u2
     JOIN user u3
     on u2.username=u3.refered
     GROUP BY u2.userid
     ) u4
ON u1.userid = u4.userid
SET u1.referrals=u4.refs
```

The join of u2 and u3 build the list of `userid` of "users being refered"
The join of u1 and u4 allows you to select from u4 and update u1